# wordpress: flat theme, change banner size

Tags: wordpress, themes, banner

I am setting up a blog with a new flat theme. I haven't used these before so please excuse me if I don't explain myself well.

This theme, [Cordillera](https://www.mageewp.com/cordillera-theme.html), comes with a full screen banner which has text layered over it. The look is great but I'd really like to be able to either a) be able to set the banner size myself or b) have it automatically adjust the container height to the image uploaded. Both being smaller than full screen, which would pull up the content below it.

Not having used this type of theme before I'm not sure what to look at to adjust this. You can check out the demo linked above or [on my blog](http://www.theoddgirl.com/). I'm not even sure what portion of code to pull out to have you start with. If you go to my blog, the section in question is the one with the angel art.

Thanks so much for looking! I appreciate any and all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add this CSS into your site :

```
.top-banner {
    width: 100%!important;
    height: 300px!important;
    background-size: contain!important;
}
```

go to "Appearance > Customize > additionnal CSS"

Comment: I added it to the custom CSS, you can see the change on the blog now.

what it looks like it did was to stretch the image to fill up the cover area but not shrink the area, if that makes sense.

Comment: not exactly, I know my explanation is lacking. I'm hoping to make the area where the image goes shrink up to the size of the image, so its no longer full screen.

Comment: oh ok, i updated my anwser so .. try the new code. You will see the **300px** you need to modify it manually in order to get the correct size. Since it's a background image we cannot make it fit exactly.